# Increasing HIT MaxAssignments

Tags: python, mechanicalturk

I would like to programmatically increase or decrease the number of opportunities based upon getting a consensus answer. For example:

- Start with 3 opportunities

  - If the first two are correct, remove the third opportunity
  - If each of the first three are different, add another opportunity
  - etc.

Is there a way to do this with mechanical turk given the HIT object? Something like:

```
hit_obj = self.conn.get_hit('MY_HIT_ID')
hit.increase_num_opps(+1) # pseudo-code
```

**Amazon Reference:**

MaxAssignments
The number of times the HIT can be accepted and completed before the HIT becomes unavailable.

Type: positive integer

Default: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`extend_hit`](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/75519b5565fcc895a567cf2c2a43338e9f8d9f52/boto/mturk/connection.py#L536) and specify the value of the `assignments_increment` parameter.